# updating openSSL gives error "files list file for package 'vim-tiny' is missing final newline"

Tags: raspbian-jessie, apt

When ever i run apt-get install with openssl or libssl-dev i get the following error

```
After this operation, 10.3 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Reading changelogs... Done
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 files list file for package 'vim-tiny' is missing final newline
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

i cannot figure out what this means or how to fix it. any suggestions?

Comment: what does the output of `cat /var/lib/dpkg/info/vim-tiny.list` look like?

Comment: The file appears to be empty

Comment: Well that's not right

Comment: i think i fixed it.  just deleted the file, updated and forced reinstall of vim-tiny

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I just deleted `/var/lib/dpkg/info/vim-tiny.list` and reinstalled `vim-tiny`.